# SQL with INNER JOIN for two tables using or before the second INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

```
    select 
    sld.linkid,sld.accept,scd.catid,scd.catname,scd.caturl,scd1.parentcatid
    from sound_link_droos sld
    INNER JOIN sound_cat_droos scd
    ON sld.catid=scd.catid 
OR
    INNER JOIN  sound_cat_droos scd1 
    ON sld.catid=scd1.parentcatid
    WHERE accept = '1' AND scd.catname = '$catname'");
```

i want to know if i can have or in this statment or ... if the one inner join return fals

sound_cat_droos

Catidcatnameparentidaccepturl
1David01http://www.example.com
2Jazz music11http://www.example.com

sound_link_droos

linkidlinknamecatidaccepturl
1my love11http://www.example.com/audio.mp3
2my baby 21http://www.example.com/audio.mp3

Comment: No, but you can have 2 `LEFT JOINS` that would act as an `OR`

Comment: can you explain it please

Comment: what is the right way to run this querry

Comment: Please, explain your aim with this query. You can't use OR operator in this way

Comment: i am afraid you'll have to [look it up](https://www.google.de/search?q=sql+left+join)

Comment: i want to get the sum of the files in sound_link_droos but some sound_cat_droos has sub files in the same table sound_link_droos

Comment: Providing example data and expected output would go a long ways towards explaining the specification. As the question is currently presented, it is *unclear* what result the statement is supposed to return. (Yes, we can include an `OR` condition in a query, and we can use an *OUTER* join operation if some rows may not have a match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a specification, we can only guess at what the query is supposed to return.

So here's a guess.

We get all `_cat_` where catname matches some value:

```
  SELECT scd.catid
       , scd.catname
       , scd.caturl
    FROM sound_cat_droos scd 
   WHERE scd.catname = 'someval'
```

We know that a `_cat_` could be the parent of other `_cat_`. And we want to also return those children `_cat_`. Here's a query to do that:

```
  SELECT scc.catid
       , scc.catname
       , scc.caturl
    FROM sound_cat_droos scc
    JOIN sound_cat_droos scp
      ON scp.catid = scc.parentcatid
   WHERE scp.catname = 'someval'
```

We can use a UNION ALL set operator to combine the results from those two queries into a single set. And then we can join that combined set to `_link_`

```
  SELECT sld.linkid
       , sld.accept
       , sca.catid
       , sca.catname
       , sca.caturl
    FROM ( SELECT scd.catid
                , scd.catname
                , scd.caturl
             FROM sound_cat_droos scd 
            WHERE scd.catname = 'someval' 
            UNION ALL 
           SELECT scc.catid
                , scc.catname
                , scc.caturl
             FROM sound_cat_droos scc
             JOIN sound_cat_droos scp
               ON scp.catid = scc.parentcatid
            WHERE scp.catname = 'someval'
         ) sca
    JOIN sound_link_droos sld
      ON sld.catid = sca.catid
     AND sld.accept = '1'
```

If it's important (for some reason) to know whether the `_cat_` we matched was a direct match, or was a match to a child `_cat_`, we can include a discriminator column in the inline view query, and return that in the resultset.

```
  SELECT sld.linkid
       , sld.accept
       , sca.catid
       , sca.catname
       , sca.caturl
       , sca.src
    FROM ( SELECT 1 AS src
                , scd.catid
                , scd.catname
                , scd.caturl
             FROM sound_cat_droos scd 
            WHERE scd.catname = 'someval' 
            UNION ALL 
           SELECT 2 AS src
                , scc.catid
                , scc.catname
                , scc.caturl
             FROM sound_cat_droos scc
             JOIN sound_cat_droos scp
               ON scp.catid = scc.parentcatid
            WHERE scp.catname = 'someval'
         ) sca
    JOIN sound_link_droos sld
      ON sld.catid = sca.catid
     AND sld.accept = '1'
```

We're just guessing at the requirements, at what result should be returned. And this query might satisfy your specification. But we don't what that specification is.

Comment: the catname on the sup folder and not the same i will give you an example : main file  catid=1 catname=music  parentcatid=0    caturl =http://www.example.com    subfolder   catid=2 catname=jazz parentcatid=1 caturl=http://www.sub.example.com

Comment: they are match on catid for the main folder and parentcatid=catid

Comment: @AlmarfahAl-islamia: please add relevant information to the *question*, do not leave it as a comment on an answer. (There's an "edit" button at the lower left of the question.) Consider formatting this example data in table format, and also show what result should be returned. Also consider setting up a test case at http://sqlfiddle.com. Clarify the specification. Absent that, we are just guessing.

Answer (score 1):

Best solution is to use Union all Instead of OR in Join as given below:

```
select sld.linkid,sld.accept,scd.catid,scd.catname,scd.caturl,scd1.parentcatid from sound_link_droos sld
INNER JOIN sound_cat_droos scd
ON sld.catid=scd.catid 
where accept = '1' and scd.catname = '$catname'
union all
select sld.linkid,sld.accept,scd.catid,scd.catname,scd.caturl,scd1.parentcatid from sound_link_droos sld
INNER JOIN  sound_cat_droos scd1 
ON sld.catid=scd1.parentcatid
where accept = '1' and scd1.catname = '$catname';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can express `or` logic in the `on` clause like this:

```
select sld.linkid, sld.accept,s cd.catid, scd.catname, scd.caturl, scd1.parentcatid
from sound_link_droos sld inner join
     sound_cat_droos scd
     on sld.catid = scd.catid or sld.catid = scd.parentcatid 
where accept = 1 and scd.catname = '$catname';
```

Such joins are usually performance killers, and this might not do what you really want.  If not, ask *another* question with sample data and desired results.

I removed the single quotes around the `'1'`, because I'm guessing the value is numeric.  Numbers should be compared to numbers.

It is also obligatory to mention parameters.  You should not be munging a query string with parameter values.  Learn how to properly use parameters.